# Construct Context Free Grammar for $\{0,1\}^*-\{www~|~w\in\{0,1\}^*\}$

Tags: computer-science, context-free-grammar

I'm working on the exercises in "Problem Solving in Automata, Languages, and Complexity" and I've run into the below problem.
The question asks to construct a CFG for the language , and I just can't figure out the correct way to do that! Could someone offer some Hints or suggestions?

$\{0,1\}^*-\{www~|~w\in\{0,1\}^*\}$

Comment: `ww | w \in {0, 1}*` is a context sensitive language, so I guess that `www | w \in {0, 1}*` should also be.